# Using COM object in parallel_for loop,

Tags: c++, com, parallel.for

In my code i am using a parallel_for loop, in this loop i am making calls from COM object, but when it runs it is not executed properly, it says something like cannot execute COM in another thread,

what i need to do, do i need to make COM multitheaded or what,

this is my code

```
COMObject myCom;
parallel_for(long(1), count, [&](long i)
{
    myCom->SomeCall(i);
});
```

Comment: How are you initializing COM? Are the threads running in that `parallel_for` initializing COM at all? And if they are, are you using `CoInitilize(NULL)` or `CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED` by any chance?

Comment: like if the loop is going to execute 10 times, then only for 3 or 4  times (depends that it is same thread) i got right output, in other cases it doesnt,

Comment: tried CoInitialize(NULL), but still not working,

Comment: All the above should be reasons for this not to work. Try initializing COM using `CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED)` on each and every thread (including the one creating `myCom`). Place that call inside the lambda too - it's ignored if COM had already been initialized for that thread.

Comment: myCom.CreateInstance(__uuidof(Client), NULL, CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER);

i m doing this to initialize my COM, what i need to do here,


i have added CoInitialize(NULL) inside parallel for,

Comment: `CreateInstance` does not initialize COM, it creates an object. You have to call `CoInitializeEx` first (unless someone is doing that already for you, before the thread runs your code). Anyhow, place that `CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED)` in your lambda, and get its return value. Using `CoInitialize(NULL)` won't work for sure.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set MTAThreadAttribute **[MTAThread]**. for more information take a look at:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.mtathreadattribute.aspx